# I am having trouble with a loop using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to make a code to loop the column b and then fill column c based on if its empty or not but its not working when I set the data into the middel of the excel sheet

```
Sub FillCellFromAbove()
Dim x As Integer
Dim y As Integer
y = Application.WorksheetFunction.Count(Range("B:B")) + 1

For x = 1 To y
    Range("C3:C7" & x).Select
    If Range("B" & x) = "" Then
        ActiveCell.Value = "Yes"
    ElseIf Range("B" & x) <> "" Then
        ActiveCell.Value = "NO"
    End If
Next x
End Sub
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

`Range("C3:C7" & x).Select` is selecting a range starting at `C3` and ending at `C71` for the first loop and `C72` for the second. Doubt that is what you want.

Also `COUNT` only counts the cells with numbers not the cells in a range from the first cell with a value to the last.  So in this case you would return 4 and do 4 loops.
Use:

```
Sub FillCellFromAbove()
    Dim x As Long
    Dim y As Long
    With ActiveSheet 'Better to set actual sheet
        y = .Cells(.Rows.Count,2).End(XlUp).Row
        For x = 3 To y
            If .Cells(x,2) <> "" Then
                .Cells(x,3) = "Yes"
            Else
                .Cells(x,3) = "No"
            End If
        Next x
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

### Flag Empty and Non-Empty Using `Evaluate`

```vb
Sub FlagEmptyNonEmpty()
    
    Const SourceColumn As String = "B"
    Const DestinationColumn As String = "C"
    Const YesFlag As String = "Yes"
    Const NoFlag As String = "No"
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet ' improve!
    
    With Intersect(ws.UsedRange, ws.Columns(SourceColumn))
        .EntireRow.Columns(DestinationColumn).Value _
            = ws.Evaluate("IF(ISBLANK(" & .Address(0, 0) & "),""" _
            & YesFlag & """,""" & NoFlag & """)")
    End With

End Sub
```